# Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config' not found in twitteroauth.php on line 15

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitterauth.php for getting twitter data in codeigniter php. It gives me error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\application\config\twitteroauth.php on line 15
```

Line 15 is

```
13 namespace Abraham\TwitterOAuth;
14 use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Util\JsonDecoder;

15 class TwitterOAuth extends Config
```

Comment: Can you post `twitterauth.php` file or link to repository you are using if so?

Comment: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/TwitterOAuth.php
this one

Comment: Best way should be using composer with vendor directory.

Comment: Any tutorial related to that?

Comment: Google for "CodeIgniter and composer".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Library's in our Codeigniter Project

You can [Download](https://github.com/epoberezkin/twitter-codeigniter) correct files and add this in relevant path as mentioned.

---

File path - `./application/`

```
Folder - config
    file name - twitter.php

Folder - controllers
    file name - twtest.php

Folder - libraries
    file name - twconnect.php 
    folder name - twitteroauth
        File name - OAuth.php
        File name - twitteroauth.php
```

Comment: Check ur authentication details